# cakePHP data inserting but should be update in edit case

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i want to save edited data in two tables in Edit case.

Table 1 : equipment_types -> to dave Equipment Types

Table 2: equipment_types_sizes -> to save Each equipment type's size.

Problem : data in Table 2 equipment_types_sizes is inserting again but should be update in edit case.

[image]

**Form HTML**

```
<input id="EquipmentTypeSize0" class="form-control valid" type="text" name="data[Sizes][0][sizes]" value="4">

<input id="EquipmentTypeSize1" class="form-control valid" type="text" name="data[Sizes][1][sizes]" value="3">

<input id="EquipmentTypeSize2" class="form-control valid" type="text" name="data[Sizes][2][sizes]" value="1">
```

**EquipmentsController.php**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->EquipmentType->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->EquipmentType->validates()) {
                $this->EquipmentType->id = $id;
                if ($this->EquipmentType->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Equipment Type has been updated successfully', 'default', 'success');
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'equipments', 'action' => 'listequipmenttypes', 'admin' => true));
                    exit;
                }

            }
}
```

**Generated Array**

```
Array
(
    [EquipmentType] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [name] => Test type 3
            [description] => dadaddas
        )

    [Sizes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sizes] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sizes] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sizes] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

**EquipmentType Model**

```
class EquipmentType extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_types';
    var $name = 'EquipmentType';
    public $cacheQueries = false;

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Sizes' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentTypesSize'
        )
    );        

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'AddedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'added_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        ),
        'ModifiedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'modified_by', 
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        )
    );


}
```

**EquipmentTypesSizes model**

```
class EquipmentTypesSizes extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'equipment_types_sizes';
    var $name = 'EquipmentTypesSizes';
    public $cacheQueries = false;
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'EquipmentType' => array(
            'className' => 'EquipmentType',
            'foreignKey' => 'equipment_type_id',
            'fields' => array('id', 'sizes')
        ),
        'AddedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'added_by',
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        ),
        'ModifiedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'modified_by', 
            'fields' => array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule1' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter Equipment Type.'
            ),
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'rule1' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Please enter Equipment description.'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: set(DATAHERE) and saveAll(DATAHERE) is a bad design. Only set your data once, then validate, then save the same data. Don't overwrite it again. So saveAll() without arguments might be a better choice when you already set and validated your data. PS: you also don't need to validate then again (what saveAll does, so make sure you disable that).

Comment: If you want to update something, then you need to pass along its ID, so the problem is most likely to be found in your edit action/view....

Answer (score 0):

Use [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)
To save data in multiple tables

Also don't forget to write correct [associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) in model

Comment: Is this worked.? If yes you can marked it's as answer :-)
Since both table are connected so if we use saveAll then it will first save to parent table then after child table
For more info Please refer to cakephp links mentioned by me in answer